# Using a file created by PHP with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using jquery to post a string to a php file like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"save0.php",
        data: {data:subtitle},
success: function() { 
      console.log("message sent!")} 
});
```

The php file then writes it into a .vtt (subtitle) file and this file is loaded back into the track element of a looping html5 video. Now every time the video loops it has a different subtitle:

```
$("#subtitles").attr("src", "subtitle/sub1.vtt");
```

I use the following line to delete the last track src (otherwise the video doesn't loop):

```
$("#subtitles").removeAttr("src");
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, it seems like the subtitle can only be used when the browser is refreshed. When the video tries to loop it just gets stuck, probably because it cannot find the track src element (I've been debugging it for a while).
Could it be that freshly written files can only be used after a refresh? Or is there an alternative way to 'load' newly written files?

Comment: Try to add to the very end of the file "?t=sfdgstye65v47" where all these symbols are random. This can make browser think that you trying to get new file instead of cached one. Like $("#subtitles").attr("src", "subtitle/sub1.vtt?t=sfdgstye65v47"); Usually for this string people use timestamp

Comment: Have you tried using JS to remove and add the video (in effect causing a reload of the video) when the data is successfully submitted?

Comment: thank you for your help, i managed to fix it by putting a bit of code in so it uses two subtitle files; when one is used the other one is altered and the other way around. That works, I'll put the code below so other people can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by alternating between subtitle files:

```
$("#subtitles").removeAttr("src");
if (subcounter == "ae"){    
            $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"save0.php",data: {data:subtitle},success: function() {console.log("message sent!")}});
            $("#subtitles").attr("src", "subtitle/sub1.vtt");
            console.log("true");
};
if (subcounter == "ea"){
            $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"save1.php",data: {data:subtitle},success: function() {console.log("message sent!")}});
            $("#subtitles").attr("src", "subtitle/sub0.vtt");
            console.log("false");
};
```

Then at the end of the loop it reverses the subcounter string:

```
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
    };

subcounter = reverse(subcounter);
```